# Show that $\frac{x}{3!}-\frac{x^3}{5!}+\frac{x^5}{7!}-\cdots\leq \frac{1}{\pi}$.

Tags: calculus, inequality, power-series

> My problem is to show that
>   $$\frac{x}{3!}-\frac{x^3}{5!}+\frac{x^5}{7!}-\cdots\leq \frac{1}{\pi}$$
>   for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

I was thinking of first finding the max and then show that its less than $1/\pi$. But it is hard to find it. I get that the series is equal to
$$f(x)=\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}.$$
Then,
$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}-\frac{2(x-\sin x)}{x^3}=0$$
if and only if
$$2\sin x=x(1+\cos x),$$
which I am unable to solve, appart from the obvious solutions $x=0$ and $x=\pi$. But if $x=\pi$ is the max, then we are done because $f(\pi)=1/\pi$.

Comment: You can rearrange that trig equation by using $\sin x = 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$ and $\cos x = \cos^2(x/2) - \sin^2(x/2)$, resulting in $\tan(x/2) = x/2$. You then might be able to deduce something about the other solutions.

Comment: The function $g(x)=tan(x)-x$ has derivate $tan^2(x)$, so in the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, $g(x)$ is strictly increasing. This shows that the only root of $g(x)$ in the given interval is $0$. Maybe this helps.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Prove that $x - \frac{x^3}{3!} < \sin x < x$ for all $x>0$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390899)

Comment: I just searched for 'sin inequality' hoping to find some questions about inequalities of that kind. There may be others.

Comment: For $x\ge 4$, we have $f(x)<\frac{x+1}{x^2}<\frac{5}{16}<\frac{1}{\pi}$ because the function $\frac{x+1}{x^2}$ strictly decreases for $x>0$.

Comment: For $x<-1$, it is clear that $f(x)$ is negative. That means, we need only consider the interval $[-1,4]$ and together with my argument for $g(x)=tan(x)-x$, it should be no problem to check it.

Comment: For $0\leq x$ we have $\sin x>x-\frac{x^3}6$ so for $x\leq\frac\pi6$: $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}<\frac x6\leq\frac1\pi$. For $x\in[0,\frac\pi2]$ we have $\sin x\geq\frac2\pi x$ so for $x\in[\pi-2,\frac\pi2]$: $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}\leq\frac{2-\pi}{\pi x}\leq\frac1\pi$. For $x\geq\pi$ we have $\sin x\geq\pi-x$ so $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}\leq\frac{2x-\pi}{x^2}\leq\frac1\pi$
(The last inequality is just $(x-\pi)^2\geq0$.) It remains to do $[-1,0]$, $[\frac\pi6,\pi-2]$ and $[\frac\pi2,\pi]$.

Answer (score 4):

Using $f(x)=\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^2}$, the inequality is equivalent to:
$$
\frac{x-\sin(x)}{x^2}≤\frac{1}{\pi}\iff x\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)≤\sin(x)
$$
Thus, define $g(x):=x\left(1-\frac{x}{\pi}\right)$.

Note that $g(x)=g(\pi-x)$ and $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-x)$. Therefore it suffices (by symmetry) to prove the inequality for $x\in\left(-\infty;\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Firstly, we prove it for $x\in\left[0;\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$:

We have $g(0)=\sin(0)=0$, thus it is sufficient to prove, that $g'(x)≤\sin'(x)$ for $x\in\left[0;\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Now: $g'(x)=1-\frac{2x}{\pi}$ and $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$. So it remains to prove: 
$$
1-\frac{2x}{\pi}≤\cos(x)
$$
Since $\cos''(x)=-\cos(x)≤0\space\forall x\in\left[0;\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, $\cos(x)$ is concave on the interval. As $g'(0)=\cos(0)=1$ and $g'\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$, $g'(x)$ connects two points on the graph of $\cos(x)$, and together with the concavity, this implies the above inequality.

Secondly, we prove it for $x\in\left(-\infty;0\right]$:

By the same argument as above, we just have to show, that on this interval $g'(x)≥\sin'(x)\iff 1-\frac{2x}{\pi}≥\cos(x)$ holds. This is true because $1-\frac{2x}{\pi}≥1≥\cos(x)$ for all $x\in\left(-\infty;0\right]$

So the inequality is indeed true.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f$ is odd. Thus, it suffices to look at the interval $[0, \infty)$.

> Lemma: For $x$ > $\pi$, we have $$\sin(x) > \frac{(\pi^2-x^2)x}{\pi^2+x^2}.$$

Proof: See 
[here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1386677/proving-that-sin-x-frac-pi2-x2x-pi2x2?rq=1)

Thus, for $x > \pi$, we have

$$
\frac{1}x - \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2} < \frac{1}x + \frac{\pi^2-x^2}{x(\pi^2+x^2)} := g(x).$$

For $x > \pi$ (or even $x > 0$), the RHS is monotonically decreasing. Thus, we can conclude that for $x \in (\pi, \infty),$ we have $$f(x) < g(\pi) = \frac{1}{\pi}.$$

Now we will find the maximum of $f$ on $[0, \pi]$. First, we check the endpoints, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$$ and $f(\pi) = \frac{1}{\pi}$.

Now we find all the extremas on our desired interval. Taking the derivative and setting it equal to $0$ gives $$2\sin(x)-x \cos(x) - x = -2 \cos(x/2)(x \cos(x/2)-2\sin(x/2)) = 0.$$ The only root of the first factor in our interval is at $x = \pi$. Now we consider $$x \cos(x/2)-2\sin(x/2) = \sqrt{x^2+4}\sin(x/2-\tan^{-1}(2/x)) = 0.$$ The roots of $\sin(\theta)$ are at multiples of $\pi$. Note that $$(x/2-\tan^{-1}(x/2))' = \frac{x^2+8}{2x^2+8}$$ so this function is strictly increasing for $x \ge 0$. Furthermore, $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^{+}} \frac{x}2- \tan^{-1}(2/x) = - \frac{\pi}2$$ and $$\frac{\pi}2 - \tan^{-1}(\pi/2) \approx 1$$ so $$\sin(x/2-\tan^{-1}(2/x))$$ has no zeroes in this interval. Thus, the global maximum is at $x = \pi$ which givse $f(\pi) = \frac{1}{\pi}$ as desired.

Answer (score -1):

That is o.k. for obtaining which solution get max and which min use second derivative test: if $f^"(a)<0$ then $a$ get max and if $f^"(a)>0$ then $a$ get min.

Comment: This only gives relative maxima and minima.

Comment: This may contradicts Jordan inequality which states: $$\frac{2}{\pi} x \le \sin x < x$$ for all $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$